# Returning partial matches in Azure Search

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

A while ago I set up a search index for a web application. One of the requirements was to return partial matches of the search terms. For instance, searching for `Joh` should find `John Doe`. The most straightforward way to implement this was to append a `*` to each search term before posting the query to Azure Search. So if a user types `Joh`, we actually ask Azure Search to search for `Joh*`.

One limitation of this approach is that all the matches of `Joh*` have the same search score. Because of this, sometimes a partial match appears higher in the results than an exact match. This is [documented behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/query-lucene-syntax#bkmk_searchscoreforwildcardandregexqueries), so I guess there is not much I can do about it. Or can I?

While my current way to return partial matches seems like a hack, it has worked well enough in practice that I didn't matter finding out how to properly solve the problem. Now I have the time to look into it and my instinct says there must be a "proper" way to do this. I have read the word "ngrams" here and there, and it seems to be part of the solution. I could probably find a passable solution after some of hours of hacking on it, but if there is any "standard way" to achieve what I want, I would rather follow that path instead of using a home-grown hack. Hence this question.

So my question is: **is there a standard way to retrieve partial matches in Azure Search, while giving exact matches a higher score?** How should I change the code below to make Azure Search return the search results I need?

### The code

Index definition, as returned by the Azure API:

```
{
    "name": "test-index",
    "defaultScoringProfile": null,
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "id",
            "type": "Edm.String",
            "searchable": false,
            "filterable": true,
            "retrievable": true,
            "sortable": false,
            "facetable": false,
            "key": true,
            "indexAnalyzer": null,
            "searchAnalyzer": null,
            "analyzer": null,
            "synonymMaps": []
        },
        {
            "name": "name",
            "type": "Edm.String",
            "searchable": true,
            "filterable": false,
            "retrievable": true,
            "sortable": true,
            "facetable": false,
            "key": false,
            "indexAnalyzer": null,
            "searchAnalyzer": null,
            "analyzer": null,
            "synonymMaps": []
        }
    ],
    "scoringProfiles": [],
    "corsOptions": null,
    "suggesters": [],
    "analyzers": [],
    "tokenizers": [],
    "tokenFilters": [],
    "charFilters": []
}
```

The documents, as posted to the Azure API:

```
{
    "value": [
        {
            "@search.action": "mergeOrUpload",
            "id": "1",
            "name": "Joh Doe"
        },
        {
            "@search.action": "mergeOrUpload",
            "id": "2",
            "name": "John Doe"
        }
    ]
}
```

Search query, as posted to the Azure API:

```
{
    search: "Joh*"
}
```

Results, where the exact match appears second, while we would like it to appear first:

```
{
    "value": [
        {
            "@search.score": 1,
            "id": "2",
            "name": "John Doe"
        },
        {
            "@search.score": 1,
            "id": "1",
            "name": "Joh Doe"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a very good question and thanks for providing a detailed explanation. The easiest way to achieve that would be to use term boosting on the actual term and combine it with a wildcard query. You can modify the query in your post to -

```
search=Joh^10 OR Joh*&queryType=full
```

This will score the documents that match Joh exactly higher. If you have more complicated requirements, you can look at constructing a custom analyzer with ngrams to search on them to support partial search.